brake will barley work
I went to replace my front right caliber on my 2011 Hyundai Sonata and re bled all my brakes but as soon as i went to drive it i had next to no braking in it at all so i assumed that it was air which there was air in it and got all of it out but when i went to drive it again and the same problem occurred but this time it didn’t get any better it got worse, it isn’t leaking any fluid and nothing is seized up on it.

If you let the brake reservoir get too low, you may have introduced air in the system that you are missing. It may have gotten into the ABS module, which sometimes has to be bled, sometimes needing a compatible scan tool. You may also consider bleeding the master cylinder as this could also have air. Once you are certain there is no air in the system, and the brake pedal still goes to the floor, the most likely problem would be a bad master cylinder. This is presuming there are no leaks.
